# Extract numbers and slashes from string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text string:

```
201408/ebrev_50000_20140804.pdf
```

I want to do an if-statement that checks if the string contains the date number and the slash: xxxxxx/ in the string. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have a look at `preg_replace`

Comment: @Daan you mean `preg_match` ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet Yep I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (preg_match("@^\d+/@", $string))
```

`^` is a zero-width anchor to the start of the string.  `\d+` is one or more digits.  `/` is a literal slash.  You can use different PCRE delimiters so you don't have to escape the slash.

If you want to get the *actual* current date, you can use `date("Ym")`, which is four-digit year and two-digit month with leading zero.  Then you wouldn't actually need to use PCRE because you have the literal string you need to match.

```
if (strpos(date("Ym") + "/", $string) === 0)
```